# Finding for the value of constant $k$ in an inequality for unique solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I got this question from an old math questionnaire and got stuck.

For which value of the constant $k$ will the following inequality have a unique solution?
$$
9k^2 (x-5)^2 - 125k^2 \geq (9+5k^2)(x^2 - 10x) + 225
$$

I tried simplifying the inequality. I expressed it as a quadratic inequality and set the discriminant as $0$ so that I would have a unique solution. But as I was about to solve for $k$, the discriminant cancelled to $0$ and I could not solve the value of $k$ anymore.

I am also new here in math.stackexchange and I do not know how to properly encode equations and inequalities. So please, bear with me.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, @ervx.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense as stated. What does it mean for the inequality to hold? For at least one $x$? For every $x$? (For every $x$ in what domain?) Perhaps for **exactly** one $x$?

Comment: I am sorry. Something went wrong when ervx edited the question. I do mean for having exactly one x.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for fixing it. Now it makes perfect sense.

Comment: I didn't do the computation, but the fact that $k$ cancels out and the discriminant is $0$ independent of $k$ is not a problem. For example, consider the inequality $(x-k)^2\le 0$. No matter what $k$ is, the discriminant is $0$, and the inequality has exactly one solution. So if you can double-check your calculation and it's fine, then you are good to go. (To convince yourself, you may want to express the whole thing as a perfect square, because that's what it means for the discriminant to be 0 regardless of $k$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $u = (x-5)^2 \implies u \ge 0$, and the inequality reduces to $f(u) = (4k^2-9)u + 100k^2 \ge 0$ for all $u \ge 0$. Observe $f$ is a linear function in $u$, thus we have: $4k^2-9 \ge 0$ or $|k| \ge \dfrac{3}{2}$.

Comment: I have changed the given. Will this strategy also work with the new question? Also, I honestly do not get your solution. Although, I would love to understand your idea. May you elaborate it a little more. Thank you very much.

Comment: if $\triangle = 0$, use the same linear function trick to settle it.

Answer (score 0):

See, your inequality is as follows,
\begin{align*}
&\quad\quad\ \  9k^2 (x-5)^2 - 25k^2-(9+5k^2)(x^2 - 10x) - 225 \ge 0\\
& \implies 9k^2(x^2-10x+25)-25k^2-9x^2+90x-5x^2k^2+50xk^2+225 \ge 0\\
& \implies9k^2x^2-90k^2x+225k^2-25k^2-9x^2+90x-5k^2x^2+50xk^2+225 \ge 0\\
& \implies x^2(4k^2-9)-x(40k^2-90)+200k^2+225 \ge 0\\
\end{align*}
This is a quadratic equation in $x$ and it is always greater than $0$  so, the discriminant has to be less than or equal to zero. Hence, $$ (40k^2-90)^2-4(4k^2-9)(200k^2+225)\le 0 .$$ Solve this for $k$ and get the solution.

I think I got your doubt, if not tell me.

Comment: I do not understand why the discriminant has to be less than or equal to zero when the quadratic expression is greater than or equal to zero. Is this a general rule? Or am I just missing something out?

Comment: Yes, this is the general rule. Why because, when the quadratic equation is greater than or equal to zero then the parabola will lie above the x-axis or just touches the axis. In the previous case, the equation does not have a real root so, the discriminant has to be less than zero and in the later case, the equation has only one root so discriminant has to be zero. So the above rule will hold always.

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I found something wrong with the given, and I have changed the question already. Given the new question, doing your solution troubles me since solving for "k" leads to 0<=0. Another thing I noticed in your suggested solution was that "-225" suddenly changed into "+225". Was this an error in your solution?

Comment: Maybe in the calculation. But you see the second solution given by @Deepsea. His solution is good. You can accept his solution.

Comment: Honestly, I would love to understand Deepsea's solution. It is just I really do not get it.

Comment: Thank you. I now understand.

Answer (score 0):

You want that $$9k^2 (x-5)^2 - 125k^2 \geq (9+5k^2)(x^2 - 10x) + 225$$ that is to say $$9k^2 (x-5)^2 - 125k^2 - (9+5k^2)(x^2 - 10x) - 225\geq 0$$ Expand and group terms to get $$\left(4 k^2-9\right) x^2+\left(90-40 k^2\right) x+(100 k^2-225) \geq 0$$ Rearranging, you have $$\left(4 k^2-9\right) x^2-10 \left(4 k^2-9\right)x+25\left(4 k^2-9\right) \geq 0$$ that is to say  $$\left(4 k^2-9\right)(x^2-10x+25) \geq 0\implies \left(4 k^2-9\right)(x-5)^2\geq 0$$ I am sure that you can take it from here